# Describing anxiety, another word for foreboding or dread

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a single word that describes that deep seated sense of dread and doom, the feeling that something in your personal world is not right, or is about to be absolutely ruined (other than foreboding)?

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demostrating how the word would be used.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fear